Angular Chart.js Charts Not Updating on Data Change Until Console is Opened
I am working on an Angular application using Chart.js to render charts. The charts initially render correctly, but they do not update when the data changes unless I open the browser's console.
Here are the relevant parts of my component:
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, takeUntil } from "rxjs";
import { KafkaAnalyticsService } from "../kafka-analytics.service";
import { UserService } from "app/core/user/user.service";
import { ChartData, ChartType, BaseChartDirective } from "ng2-charts";

@Component({
  selector: "app-kafka-analytics-list",
  templateUrl: "./kafka-analytics-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./kafka-analytics-list.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class KafkaAnalyticsListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('lineChart') lineChart: BaseChartDirective;
  @ViewChild('barChart') barChart: BaseChartDirective;

  private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  public TicketLineChartData: ChartData<"line"> = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [],
  };

  public TicketBarChartData: ChartData<"bar"> = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [],
  };

  constructor(
    private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private _kafkaAnalyticsService: KafkaAnalyticsService,
    private _userService: UserService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._kafkaAnalyticsService.kafkaTickets$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.updateCharts(response);
          // Ensure Angular detects changes
          this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._unsubscribeAll.next(null);
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
  }

  updateCharts(response): void {
    // Process response and update chart data
    // ...

    if (this.lineChart) {
      console.log('Updating line chart');
      this.lineChart.update();
    } else {
      console.log('Line chart is not available');
    }

    if (this.barChart) {
      console.log('Updating bar chart');
      this.barChart.update();
    } else {
      console.log('Bar chart is not available');
    }
  }

  getTicketsTime(time): void {
    // Logic to get tickets based on time
    // ...
    this._kafkaAnalyticsService.updateTickets(startDate, endDate)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe();
  }
}

The HTML Template:
                Kafka Tickets ({{time}})

                
              </div>
              <div class="text-secondary font-medium">Trend of Kafka tickets opened</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-2">
              <button class="justify-items-end" mat-flat-button [color]="'primary'" [disabled]="isLoading"
                  [matTooltip]="'Submit'" [matMenuTriggerFor]="timeMenu">
                  Select Time
                </button>
                <mat-menu #timeMenu="matMenu">
                  <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let time of date_selection" [value]="time"
                    (click)="getTicketsTime(time)">
                    {{ time }}
                  </button>
                </mat-menu>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col flex-auto mt-6">
            <canvas baseChart class="lineChart" [data]="TicketLineChartData" [type]="lineChartType"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col flex-auto mt-6">
            <canvas baseChart class="barChart" [data]="TicketBarChartData" [type]="barChartType"> </canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>

The charts when initially loading onto the page are perfect, but when selecting a new time, they do not update unless going to the console.

Two things you can try to fix the issue.
Try to use detectChanges instead of markForCheck.
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._kafkaAnalyticsService.kafkaTickets$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.updateCharts(response);
          // Ensure Angular detects changes
          this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // <- changed here!
        }
      });
  }

It might be that you are updating the properties of TicketLineChartData and TicketBarChartData but that does not change the memory reference (arrays and objects are stored as memory references and not by value) so we can update to a new memory ref using destructuring which might trigger a change detection.
  updateCharts(response): void {
    // Process response and update chart data
    // ...

    if (this.lineChart) {
      console.log('Updating line chart');
      this.TicketLineChartData = [...this.TicketLineChartData]; // <- changed here!
    } else {
      console.log('Line chart is not available');
    }

    if (this.barChart) {
      console.log('Updating bar chart');
      this.TicketBarChartData = [...this.TicketBarChartData]; // <- changed here!
    } else {
      console.log('Bar chart is not available');
    }
  }

